# What is the syntax for adding parameters to the called procedure in Oracle scheduler?

Tags: oracle, syntax, scheduler

So say I have 2 procedures: MYPROC1 & MYPROC2(A_PARAM INTEGER)

this works:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
        job_name => 'TEST_SCHEDULER',
        job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
        job_action => 'developer.MYPROC1', <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        start_date => TIMESTAMP'2011-12-4 10:30:00',
                repeat_interval => 'FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=30',
        end_date => TIMESTAMP'2011-12-4 10:45:00',
        auto_drop => FALSE,
        comments => 'TEST 1');
END;
```

replacing line 5 with:

`job_action => 'developer.MYPROC1(2)'` makes it not work.
Error: ..invalid name for a database object...

So how do I call from a scheduler a parametrized procedure? Whats the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', job_action => 'BEGIN developer.MYPROC1(2); END;'` instead.

Comment: That did the job! Nice.Thank you

Comment: @IftimieVlad you are welcome :-) please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

Leave your `job_action` parameter as it is (without the arguments), and add the `number_of_arguments` option to the number if parameters your procedure expects.

You can then use [`DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10802/d_sched.htm#1010949) to set the argument values.

Examples here: [Using jobs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse002.htm).

Comment: thanks, learned something new... didn't know about that option :-)

Answer (score 0):

- Firsly, create your scheduler job by using `DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB` without enabling (default is false, already), and then that should be enabled to run.
- It' nice to define `job_name` parameter as a bind variable for consecutive job names.
- `job_name` parameter needn't to be in upper cases, but when querying scheduler run history, call it with all letters of `job_name` in upper from a privileged schema :

  ```
  select * 
    from dba_scheduler_job_log l
   where l.job_name = 'TEST_SCHEDULER'
   order by l.log_date desc;
  ```
- Don't forget to include `number_of_arguments`(for this case it equals `1`) parameter for your job creation command.
- As Mat tells you may use `DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE` like in the following example ( also define `argument value` parameter as a bind variable with value `2` as in your case ) :

  ```
  BEGIN  
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
       job_name => '&v_job_name', -- tEst_sCheDuLEr
       job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
       job_action => 'developer.MYPROC1', 
       number_of_arguments => 1,
       start_date => '04-apr-2018 10:30:00 am',
       repeat_interval => 'FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=3;',
       end_date => '04-apr-2018 10:45:00 am',
       auto_drop => false,
       comments => 'TEST 1');

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE(
       job_name => '&v_job_name', 
       argument_position => 1,
       argument_value => &vl -- 2
       );

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE('&v_job_name');    
  END;
  ```

If you get *`ORA-01882` Timezone region not found* error, then

`to_timestamp_tz('04-APR-2018 10:30:00 EST', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZR')` 
or `to_date('04.04.2018 10:30:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`
format may be used for `start_date` parameter.